# Trying to ID a piece.

Tags: part-identification

Light grey, approx. 1 in. X 1 in. Shaped like a bottom jaw or a digger shovel. It has a half round hump in the middle of the piece.

Comment: If you had a picture of the piece it would make things so much easier. Or if you could tell us some more about it, like does it have studs, inverted studs, pin holes, axle holes, does it have some kind of texture or print? What kind of set does it belong to or where did you see it?

Comment: Adding a picture for part identification is definitively a must.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty sure you're describing a [Bionicle Krana Holder 3 x 4](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=42042), which allegedly comes in light grey, dark grey, brown, red, blue, and green.

Comment: +1 bonus point for getting that deducted from the OP's fuzzy description :)

Comment: I got lucky. I acquired several a while back and had to find out what they were and went digging on BrickLink. Still haven't figured out what to do with them...